# Access variables from protected sub to another protected sub (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm sorry if this is stupid question. I'm new to vb.net and still learning. My assignment was to create a online web form where it will collect user data and item they want to purchase. The form contains textboxes with four buttons.

[image]

I want to pass variables from protected sub Add Item buttons to another protected sub Finish Button to calculate final totals.

I have done some research on how to do this but haven't really find a solution. Hope you could help me. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Paul Le, are you able to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40666447/edit) your question add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Preferably, your example should include what you have tried to do to solve this problem yourself. Also avoid adding your code to the question as an image. It makes it very hard for people to recreate your problem.

Comment: Please don't take sceenshots of your source code... If we wanted to try it ourselves, we'd have to type it out again. There's an excellent code formatting system built into SO, so take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your mental model is wrong. The methods (Subs) you're in are executed when the button is clicked. As soon as they've finished running, they're gone forever, along with all their variables. There are a few cases where you preserve variables for longer, but they're a little more advanced.

What you need to do is have a variable somewhere in a "shared" memory scope. You do this by declaring it outside of the method...

```
Private Data as String
Protected Sub Button1_Click(...)
    Data = "Button Clicked"
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(...)
    Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", Data)
End Sub
```

This is commonly known as a private field.